# python define a state object

Tags: python, state

I wrote the following code:

```
class Game(object):
    class States(object):
        STARTED = 1 << 0
        LOADING = 1 << 1
        ACTIVE = 1 << 2
        ENDED = 1 << 3

    state = States.LOADING
```

It there any better way to define a state object?

Comment: Why are you using bits? Aren't the states mutually exclusive?

Comment: All I need is to be able to make comparison like `if state and States.LOADING`

Comment: I guess this works, but it doesn't seems to be the best practice to do so..

Comment: Is it really nessecery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have seen this pattern:

```
class Demo:
     STARTED, LOADING, ACTIVE, ENDED = range(4)
```

or if you really need distinct bits:

```
class Demo:
     STARTED, LOADING, ACTIVE, ENDED = (2**x for x in range(4))
```

That said, why do you want to burden yourself with doing bit manipulations? Just use boolean properties:

```
class States(object):
    def __init__(self):
         self.started = False
         self.loading = False
         self.active = False
         self.ended = False
```

which allows you to write:

```
if state.loading:
```

and

```
if state.started or state.loading:
```

which is much more readable.

Comment: It can only be 1 state at a time

Comment: in that case, you should avoid bitsets because they mean "can be any number of them at the same time."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.  Use the new Python [Enum type](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0435/) (which has also been [backported](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34)).  Then your code would be:

```
class State(Enum):
    STARTED = 1
    LOADING = 2
    ACTIVE = 3
    ENDED = 4

class Game(object):
    state = State.LOADING
```